# Why I have the error: ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699)

Tags: conda

I have tried to use conda to install gcc-5 -c psi4, then I use

```
conda install gcc-5 -c psi4
```

on my ubuntu20.

However, it appeared:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'psi4::gcc-5-5.2.0-1'.
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a very old package from an uncommon channel. There is a GCC 5.4 available through the **defaults** channel:

```bash
conda install -c anaconda gcc_linux-64=5

## example usage
$GCC --version

x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc (crosstool-NG fa8859cb) 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Likely more expedient than debugging the **psi4** one.